# Which EOF check method should I use?

Tags: java, io, deserialization

I'm currently preparing for my OCP exam and found this snipped which deserializes a list of Objects:

```
public static List<Animal> getAnimals(File dataFile) throws IOException,
        ClassNotFoundException {
    List<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<Animal>();
    try (ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(
            new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(dataFile)))) {
        while (true) {
            Object object = in.readObject();
            if (object instanceof Animal)
                animals.add((Animal) object);
        }
    } catch (EOFException e) {
    // File end reached
    }
    return animals;
}
```

However I consider the `while(true)` and the swallowed exception as ugly code.
Could I just use `in.available > 0` as the while condition?

Since JavaDoc says:

> Returns the number of bytes that can be read without blocking.

I'm not sure if this could have any side effects?

Comment: BTW, there is a bug in the try-with-resources here. Do you know what it is? (Since you're preparing for an exam).

Comment: let me see... the exception possibly thrown by the `close()` method wouldn't get caught?

Comment: No, that's guaranteed by the spec. But you're right that it's to do with exceptions. Think about what happens (or doesn't happen) if `dataFile` isn't a valid object stream.

Comment: One of the Streams would throw an IOException? But I can't see an issue there..

Comment: The problem is that the `FileInputStream` isn't closed if any of the wrapping constructors throw an exception. Following the maxim of "don't close a stream you didn't open" (*), constructors don't close parameter streams if they don't complete successfully. You should specify the `FIS` as a separate variable in the try-with-resources statement to guarantee it's closure, or file handles may leak.

Comment: * `close()` methods of many streams *do* close wrapped streams, violating this rule. This is a particularly irksome relic of the days before TWR.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with checking `available()` is that there might not be data available, but still you're not at the end of the stream. For example, you could be reading the data over a network connection, which happens to have stalled part-way through sending the data. You're not at EOF; the next byte of data just hasn't arrived yet.

---

Whilst I don't like using exceptions to detect things you expect under normal conditions (like reaching the end of the stream), the Javadoc of [`EOFException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/EOFException.html) indicates that this is how you're meant to detect end of the stream:

> Signals that an end of file or end of stream has been reached unexpectedly during input.
>
> This exception is mainly used by data input streams to signal end of stream. Note that many other input operations return a special value on end of stream rather than throwing an exception.

But `ObjectInputStream.readObject()` isn't one of the operations which returns a special value.

So, hold your nose, and catch that exception.

Comment: I like the network connection example. Exactly what I was looking for :) Thanks! *holds his nose and catches the exception*